# How to read a column header with a line break into Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv column heading:
`"Submission S
tatus"`

csv headers:

```
Unit,Publication ID,Title,"Submission S
tatus",Notes,Name,User ID
```

How can I refer to this when reading into the dataframe with the `usecols` parameter (or alternatively when renaming at a later stage)?

I have tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', usecols = ['Submission S\ntatus']
```

error: `Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found`

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', usecols = ['Submission S\rtatus']
```

error: `Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found`

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', usecols = ['Submission S
tatus']
```

error: `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

How should I be referring to this column?

Comment: could you show a example of your csv?

Comment: OK - I have done that

Comment: @MrDave  can you share how you have done that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer you wanted, but I hope it will help you if you want any workaround for this.

`df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', usecols = [n])`
`df.rename(columns={df.columns[n]: "new column name"}, inplace=True)`
`# n is your column postion`

Answer (score 0):

You can read a csv file using the traditonal way of statements:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
saved_column = df.column_name
```

You can save the column names by

```
colnames = df.Names
```

Later replace the name of your specified column using a meaningful word